# solr 4.6 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: first position increment must be > 0 (got 0)

Tags: java, solr

I Have a problem that is randomly reproducing when updating solr(4.6) documents.

```
"error": {
    "msg": "first position increment must be > 0 (got 0) for field 'any_field'",
    "trace": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: first position increment must be > 0 (got 0) for field 'any_field'
    org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverterPerField.processFields(DocInverterPerField.java:125)
    org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.processDocument(DocFieldProcessor.java:248)
    org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:253)
    org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:453)
    org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1520)
    org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:217)
    org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
    org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
    org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:569)
    org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:705)
    org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:435)
    org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
    org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:126)
    org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:101)
    org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:65)
    org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
    org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1859)
    org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:710)
    org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:413)
    org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)",
    "code": 500
}
```

The any_field's analyzer is below:
`<fieldType name="text_paoding" class="solr.TextField"/>
       <analyzer class="net.paoding.analysis.analyzer.PaodingAnalyzer"/></analyzer/>
    </fieldType/>`

Comment: The Error is Self Explanatory, the Value of any_field Should be greater then 0,

Comment: Here is an example for which the error is returned:  "any_field": "Test SomeName 1 and some description"

Comment: To be more specific, the update is always working just fine the first time after the solr was started. After the first request, it works randomly.